# onedit script in google sheet works for only one function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 scripts in the same project but it seems that only one is working, not specific but depending on the time I add the script, it is like the last script Im adding disabling the other.

these are the 2 scripts (I copied from  google forum and updated according to my needs):

1. adding an auto time stamp to a cell when specified range is not empty:

```
 function onEdit(event) {
      var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var c = sp.getActiveCell();
      if (c.getColumn() < 9 && sp.getName()=='QUE') {
        var celladdresp ='I'+ c.getRowIndex() 
        sp.getRange(celladdresp).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yy hh:mm");
      }
    };
```

2. copy a row to another sheet on the same file if checkbox is checked (=true):

```
   function onEdit(event) {
         var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
         var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
         var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
         if(s.getName() == "QUE" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == true) { var row = r.getRow();
           var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
           var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QUE2");
           var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
           s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns-2).copyTo(target);
         }   
   };
```

Your help understanding why they dont work together will be appreciated.
*BTW I tried to Enable/Disable new apps scriptspowered by chrome v8 but did not helped

Comment: Every function has to have a different name you’ll have to combine the two functions in the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can only have one `onEdit(event)` function per script. If you wish both functions to run on edit, you need to combine them.*

#### More Information

It's programming 101 that all functions and variables have to have unique names - otherwise your code isn't going to know *which* function or variable you're referring to. The uniqueness is important as you're defining exactly what you want.

In this case, as you have two `onEdit(event)` functions, when the sheet is edited your script is only calling one of these functions. This makes sense - it has no reason to continue looking for more `doGet()`s if it's already found and executed one.

#### Merging Functions:

When merging, it's important not to replicate code that is unneccesary. Reducing the number of calls so you only do exactly what you need to is important for efficient-running code:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var c = sheet.getActiveCell();  

  if (c.getColumn() < 9 && sheet.getName() == 'QUE') {
    var celladdresp = 'I' + c.getRowIndex() 
    sheet.getRange(celladdresp).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yy hh:mm");
  }

  if(sheet.getName() == "QUE" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == true) { var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QUE2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns-2).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```